# Spring Error libraries

Tags: eclipse, spring, libraries

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:10)
```

I have add these libraries

```
commons-collections-3.1
spring-aop-4.0.0.M1
spring-aspects-4.0.0.M1
spring-beans-4.0.0.M1
spring-context-4.0.0.M1
spring-context-support-4.0.0.M1
spring-core-4.0.0.M1
antlr-2.7.2
```

My code:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
    obj.getMessage();
}
 }


public class HelloWorld {

private String message;
public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
}
public void getMessage(){
    System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
}
 }
```

Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
 3.0.xsd"
 >
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
    <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that spring framework is internally using commons logging. Hence, adding commons-logging.jar into your lib folder should solve the problem.

Jar can be downloaded from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [jarfinder.com](http://jarfinder.com) is good for this. [This query](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory~) gives me

```
17 classes match your query :-

org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
....
```

and selecting that class gives me [the candidate jars](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory)

```
abstract class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory [6781 bytes, jvm >= 1.2 ]

    commons-logging.jar
    appserv-rt.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The code needs a logging implementation.  I believe Spring prefers `SLF4J` add the following to your pom or classpath:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging) regarding logging in Spring.

Comment: He is probably not using Maven and he definitely does not have SLF4J on classpath ;).